# Why can't I change a field in a child class unless its within a method C#

Tags: c#, field

Hi this is probably a very basic answer but I can't find it when googling it.

Basically I understand the basics to how inheritance works however I can't understand with a small example code I was playing around with to practice inheritance that I can only change the value of an int set in the parent class in the child class when its in a method with shapeSize for this example:

```
    public class Shape
{
   public int shapeSize = 1;
    public virtual void Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Draw a shape");
        ShowShapeSize();
    }

    private void ShowShapeSize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(shapeSize);

    }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
       //Can't change value here of shapeSize here??
    public override void Draw()
    {
        shapeSize = 2;
        base.Draw();
        Console.WriteLine("Testing none override");
    }

}
```

Can someone please explain why I can't change the field in the area I've placed the comment but why I can in methods.

Comment: You can't put code outside a method.

Comment: I thought with fields I could change the fields within the child class itself? Well I guess not must be the answer. Why is that?

Comment: Because you can only put code inside a method.

Comment: You can make an overridable property (overriding it in the subclass), but fields are just memory; to change them, you need to run code, and to run code, you need an execution context like a method. Properties aren't just memory, they are a pair of functions (a getter and a setter). Why is it like that? Uh, 'cause that's the way the language is designed.

Comment: Ok I get it now was confused as I thought if it inherited the same fields I would be able to change them in the same location but it makes sense now with what you've said about the getter and setter. As I understand in other contexts code needs to be called in a method.

Thanks

Comment: When you wrote `public int shapeSize = 1;` in `Shape` class, it is essentially equivalent to do the initialization at the beginning of the constructor